# Shared drives to sharepoint to onedrive

Tags: sharepoint, migration, onedrive

I have a need to transfer my user files that were once in a shared drive and now exist in sharepoint to onedrive. The company moved their existing file shares to sharepoint and they now have any to move the user files to onedrive. I have tried using spmt to move these files but it doesn’t recognize my sharepoint online address. Any suggestions?

Tried spmt.

Comment: Whether you want to migrate SharePoint files to OneDrive?